# Objective-C: Cross correlation of two audio files

Tags: ios, objective-c, vdsp

I want to perform a cross-correlation of two audio files (which are actually `NSData` objects). I found a `vDSP_convD` function in `accelerate framework`. `NSData` has a property `bytes` which returns a pointer to an array of voids - that is the parameter of the filter and signal vector.

I struggled with other parameters. What is the length of these vectors or the length of the result vectors?

**I guess:**

> it's the sum of the filter and signal vector.

Could anyone give me an example of using the `vDSP_convD` function?

Apple reference to the function is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_convD)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a call would look like this:

```
vDSP_conv ( signal *, signalStride, filter *, filterStride, result*, resultStride, resultLenght, filterLength );
```

where we have:

- signal*: a pointer to the first element of your signal array
- signalStride: the lets call it "step size" throug your signal array. 1 is every element, 2 is every second ...
- same for filter and result array
- length for result and filter array

How long do the arrays have to be?:

As stated in the docs you linked our signal array has to be **lenResult + lenFilter - 1** which it is where it gets a little messy. You can find a demonstration of this by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/vDSPExamples/Listings/DemonstrateConvolution_c.html) or a shorter answer by SO user Rasman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917951/perform-autocorrelation-with-vdsp-conv-from-apple-accelerate-framework/#answer-10920028).
You have to do the zero padding of the signal array by yourself so the vector functions can apply the sliding window without preparation.

**Note:** You might consider using the Fast-Fourier-Transformation for this, because when you work with audio files i assume, that you have quite some data and there is a significant performance increase from a certain point onwards when using:

FFT -> complex multiplication in frequency domain (which results in a correlation in time domain) -> reverse FFT

[here](https://github.com/kunalkandekar/vDSPxcorr) you can find a useful piece of code for this!

Answer (score 0):

After reading a book - Learning Core Audio, I have made a demo which demonstrates delay between two audio files. I used new iOS 8 API to get samples from the audio files and a good performance optimization.

[Github Project](https://github.com/Vaberer/audio_time_shifting).